.NET Core 6.0 Routing is Not working if i use areas
I have project with areas and normal controller in it. But Area routing is working but normal controller is not working.
Working, but Areas routing is returning 404 :
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

Working for Area routing but not root controller :
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

I have other 3 project with same scenarios but that are working but facing issue with my recently created project.

I have to add both then its working :
app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

Hi @Abhijeet Patil, if you want to make the area and default routing work, you must add the two route templates.

References : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-6.0
You have to specify two routes with different names.
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "area",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);

After that you have to use [Area] attribute to specify which Controller belongs to which Area.
 [Area("Admin")]


Hi, Yes. I did the same already. it is working. but in my other project I've used only one route and its working for both area and normal controller. There was no need to use both. that is why it is puzzling me. I thought The Microsoft may have made some changes recently.

@AbhijeetPatil, I am not sure about it, Maybe you specify route in area controller directly using [Controller] Attribute.

You must add the default route template together with area route template to make all the default and area routing work.
I think you may misunderstand the area:exists meaning. exists applies a constraint that the route must match an area. Using {area:...} with MapControllerRoute:

Is the least complicated mechanism to adding routing to areas.
Matches all controllers with the [Area("Area name")] attribute

Reference: Areas in ASP.NET Core
